# mAuth=Firebase.getInstance() giving error while running application

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

When I run application it always stop on me. Help.

[image: 1]

`mAuth=Firebase.getInstance()` is giving a problem in the android monitor and could not find the solution been stuck on this for days and searching for the answer but no luck. help me out

Comment: what Firebase service are you using? Also what error gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase.getInstance() cannot be called on main thread or UI thread, that might be the reason. Try it in worker thread or AsyncTask.